# Creating a batch file for ffmpeg to combine image sequence to mkv

Tags: image, batch-file, ffmpeg, sequence

I have been doing some work remastering some videos by converting them to image sequences, editing them, then converting them back to videos. To do the last step, I have been just using the command prompt with ffmpeg. My goal is to create a batch file that I can just put into the folder with my image sequence and run it rather than needing to do it through the command prompt manually.

Here is the command I've been running:
`"C:\Program Files (x86)\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe" -framerate 23.97 -i "%06d.png" -c:v copy "B:\output.mkv"`

ffmpeg is located on my C drive, the image sequences are on my Z drive, but I generally move to that folder to run the command, and the images are always named with 6 digits (000000.png-######.png). The output file is created on the B drive.

I assumed that I could just add that command to a .bat file

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\RipBot264v1.25.1\Tools\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe" -framerate 23.97 -i "%06d.png" -c:v copy "B:\output.mkv"

pause
```

but I have not been able to get it to work. When I try to run it, I get an error that seems to be related to the name of the batch file itself:

> Z:\S09E19"Z:\S09E19_Output.bat6d.png -c:v copy B:\output.mkv: Invalid argument

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Percent symbols have special meaning in a batch file and must be escaped if the program requires a literal use of the percent symbol.  To do that you have to double the percent symbol.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I did try that, but I get the same error when trying to run it.